# New line not displayed in Artifact notes of Enterprise Architect

Tags: vba, element, enterprise-architect

I am working on the VBA scripting in Enterprise Architect, I tried to automate the creation of the elements(Artifact type) from excel.

My goal is to read the excel row by row and create the elements based on the names in the excel column and add the notes which I can get from another column. I implemented the following code.

```
 'objExcel is an Excel application object
 For i = 2 To rowCount
    id = objExcel.Cells(i,1).Value
    notes = objExcel.Cells(i,2).Value
    set element = elements.AddNew( id, "Artifact")
    'notes = Replace(notes, "\n", "\r\n")
    'notes = Replace(notes, Chr(13) + Chr(10), "\r\n")
    notes = Replace(notes, vbNewLine, "\r\n")
    element.Update()    
Next
```

Now the problem is, The description inside the notes is not displaying the new lines, it shows as a single line. There is a similar question is there in StackOverflow but that solution also not working.

```
ele.Notes = "111" + "\n" + "222\r\n333"";
ele.Update();
```

I tried the above code also but still the issue is there,its displaying as 111\n222\r\n333 in EAP.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert into an Excel cell some text with additional line breaks by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
these are stored as `CHR(10)` (which is the same as `vbLf` in VBA).

A lot of Windows based text formats use a combination of a "line feed" and a "carriage return" instead (`CHR(10)` and `CHR(13)`, equivalent to `vbCrLf`).

So please try:

```
notes = Replace(notes, vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

For more alternatives and differences between Windows and MacOS see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants).

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert text for notes with

```
formatted = Repository.GetFieldFromFormat (string Format, string Text)
```

Converts the value Text from the Format ‘HTML’, ‘RTF’ or ‘TXT’ to Enterprise Architect’s internal format. You can skip that if you just use plain ASCII above x1F and below x80.

For example you use it like

```
element.Notes =
  Repository.GetFieldFromFormat ("HTML", "<ol><li>one<li>two<ol>"); 
if (!element.Update ()) print "Update failed";
```

Vice versa

```
html = GetFormatFromField(("HTML", element.Notes)
```

will return a HTML string from the notes property of the element.

Comment: Well, yes. The accepted answer will fix _this_ issue. But EA's notes are _Sparxian_ and need to be handled with the `Repository` operation (and its pendant) in general.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried the following `notes = Repository.GetFieldFromFormat ("TXT", notes)`.But it is not working, I don't know how to use the above function exactly.

Comment: Ah yes, _Sparxian_ thinking is required ;-) I have updated the answer.